# Update ASP.NET Core packages from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I just checked my ASP.NET Core 2.0 packages in a project I am working on.  I noticed that there are a series of updates from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1.  I decided to update my packages.  I started getting an error in updating as follows:

Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.3 to 2.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

I go out into nuget and see that the Microsoft.NETCore.App package has indeed been updated to 2.0.3 3 days ago, but I am not trying to update that package.  That package appears to be a dependent package for what I am trying to update.  One of the packages I am trying to update is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1.

Any ideas on how to update?  Should I just have some patience until some other packages roll out?  I am guessing that with Microsoft.Connect() this week, there are a series of rollouts, but wanted to at least ask about this.

Thanks.

Comment: also, I stopped and restart Visual Studio 2017, the local iis web dev server, and rebooted my machine.

Comment: Sharing your `.csproj` might help. Why don't you just upgrade all the packages?

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade all the packages and VS nuget won't let me.

Comment: So,k I decided to go look at my csproj.  I decided to manually change the package references to 2.0.1 as necessary.  Doing this to the offending packages resulted in the fixing of the errors.  Not sure if this was a good idea or not, but wanted to say thanks for the suggestion.  :-)

Comment: I also had the worst difficulties to update. It took me a while to update those packages. It seems the "Manage Nugets package for the solutions" is buggy. I had to use command line to update my package.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend updating packages from commandline one by one in order of dependencies. That would clearly give error on package to be updated.
You can use below query in package manager console: 
Update-Package [PackageName] -ProjectName [ProjectName] -Version [VersionToBeUpdated]